# Subtotal of all items in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

Query below currently shows the total as item by item but what I want is to calculate subtotal of all items in a purchase order.

Thanks

**Output should be:**

```
POID Item ItemQTY ItemPrice  ItemTotal   SubTotal
1      A       1     15.00       15.00      80.50
1      B       1     25.50       25.50      80.50
1      C       2     20.00       40.00      80.50
2      X       6      5.00       30.00      50.00
2      Y       2     10.00       20.00      50.00
```

**Relationship**: `purchase_order 1 - N purchase_order_items`

```
SELECT
purchase_order.id AS POID,

purchase_order_items.description AS Item,
purchase_order_items.quantity AS ItemQTY,
purchase_order_items.price AS ItemPrice,
(purchase_order_items.quantity*purchase_order_items.price) AS ItemTotal

/* Here, Subtotal should be calculated and displayed */

FROM purchase_order
INNER JOIN purchase_order_items ON purchase_order.id = purchase_order_items.fk_purchase_order
```

I looked at [MySQL finding subtotals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397384/mysql-finding-subtotals) and [Subtotals and SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516261/subtotals-and-sql) but couldn't apply to my query.

Comment: You can calculate this in your server-side script with a loop. Either that, you can do an inner `SELECT` in your above query.

Comment: It would be much nicer as a separate value as the subtotal doesn't logically make sense against each row of your data. You should either call a separate method/sql proc to get the total or calculate it on the returned data via code/some other method.

Comment: @Tanner - It is possible. See the accepted answer below please.

Comment: @MadMax I know it's possible, it's just not logical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT i.fk_purchase_order POID,
       description         Item,
       quantity            ItemQTY,
       price               ItemPrice,
       quantity * price    ItemTotal,
       s.subtotal          SubTotal
  FROM purchase_order_items i JOIN
(
  SELECT fk_purchase_order, SUM(quantity * price) subtotal
    FROM purchase_order_items
   GROUP BY fk_purchase_order
) s ON i.fk_purchase_order = s.fk_purchase_order
```

Output:

```
| POID | ITEM | ITEMQTY | ITEMPRICE | ITEMTOTAL | SUBTOTAL |
------------------------------------------------------------
|    1 |    A |       1 |        15 |        15 |     80.5 |
|    1 |    B |       1 |      25.5 |      25.5 |     80.5 |
|    1 |    C |       2 |        20 |        40 |     80.5 |
|    2 |    X |       6 |         5 |        30 |       50 |
|    2 |    Y |       2 |        10 |        20 |       50 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/755ea8/4)** demo

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `WITH ROLLUP` feature to get subtotals:

```
SELECT
purchase_order.id AS POID,

purchase_order_items.description AS Item,
purchase_order_items.quantity AS ItemQTY,
purchase_order_items.price AS ItemPrice,
SUM(purchase_order_items.quantity*purchase_order_items.price) AS ItemTotal
FROM purchase_order
INNER JOIN purchase_order_items ON purchase_order.id = purchase_order_items.fk_purchase_order
GROUP BY POID, Item WITH ROLLUP
```

This will create a result set that has `Item = NULL` for the PO subtotal, and `POID = NULL` for a grand total. These subtotals and grand totals go in the `ItemTotal` column of those rows.

Comment: Very interesting. I'll remember that. +1

Answer (score 0):

Afraid I think the best solution is to cross join against a subselect:-

```
SELECT
purchase_order.id AS POID,
purchase_order_items.description AS Item,
purchase_order_items.quantity AS ItemQTY,
purchase_order_items.price AS ItemPrice,
(purchase_order_items.quantity*purchase_order_items.price) AS ItemTotal,
Sub1.FullTotal
FROM purchase_order
INNER JOIN purchase_order_items ON purchase_order.id = purchase_order_items.fk_purchase_order
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT  SUM(purchase_order_items.quantity*purchase_order_items.price) AS FullTotal
    FROM purchase_order
    INNER JOIN purchase_order_items ON purchase_order.id = purchase_order_items.fk_purchase_order
) Sub1
```

To bring it back for grouped purchase order ids

```
SELECT
purchase_order.id AS POID,
purchase_order_items.description AS Item,
purchase_order_items.quantity AS ItemQTY,
purchase_order_items.price AS ItemPrice,
(purchase_order_items.quantity*purchase_order_items.price) AS ItemTotal,
Sub1.FullTotal
FROM purchase_order
INNER JOIN purchase_order_items ON purchase_order.id = purchase_order_items.fk_purchase_order
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT purchase_order.id, SUM(purchase_order_items.quantity*purchase_order_items.price GROUP BY purchase_order.id) AS FullTotal
    FROM purchase_order
    INNER JOIN purchase_order_items ON purchase_order.id = purchase_order_items.fk_purchase_order
) Sub1
ON purchase_order.id = Sub1.id
```

Comment: Because of my mistake your query returns subtotal of all the purchase orders. I meant, sub total of all purchase orders individually. I updated the question.